# Custom MySql Image w/ Data in Kubernetes

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes

I created and pushed a mysql image that contains schemas (call it myServiceDB), data to our local docker repository to be pulled down via a kubernetes. It finds the container and installs it but none of the data shows up when I connect to the DB in Kubernetes. I get a blank mysql with none of my pre-baked data.

However if i load that same docker image via docker compose locally on my machine it works and the data is there.

The use case here is more of an internal usecase where we can deploy different versions of the db with custom pre-baked data so we can easily set up scenarios to run through tests. (These instances are short lived). Not sure if this is the best approach, but i want to explore it.

The question:

Does loading a custom mysql image with data not work in Kubernetes? My Kubernetes setup looks like this:
`mysql-service.yaml`
`mysql-volumeclaim.yaml`
`mysql.yaml`

similar to this one here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes-engine-samples/tree/main/wordpress-persistent-disks with my custom image replacing the image in the mysql.yaml deployment.

Comment: Looking at that github project, it is configuring a Persistent Volume to store the DB contents, which is important in K8S.  I am not seeing anything there that initializes the DB though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference for how the image works running in kubernetes vs docker.  I would double-check that the right version of the image is actually used by the pods.

If the database was populated by scripts in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory, verify those files are actually there in the pod, and check the permissions.

`kubectl exec -it ...` can be used to poke around the inside of a pod.

Comment: Thanks @ash, The database image (docker tag, docker commit, docker push etc.) is a snapshot of my local docker image of the DB with data. I just want to load it into k8s but it doesn't show up. I'll dig around a bit more to see what i can find. I didn't use /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d because the image already contains the data i need.

Comment: In that case, it's a matter of getting that image (with the right name and tag) loaded into K8S, or making it available to K8S to pull, then when creating the pod, using that image (again, with the right name and tag).

Comment: The command `kubectl describe pod/...` can be used to verify the image.